# Can I change the UIBezierPath frame after it is created

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-animation

Its coordinates and size ?

```
 path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
 fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
 fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

or do I need to recreate the path and set it to fillLayer.path again

Comment: There is no method to do that but you can apply(CGAffineTransform)

Comment: For example like this: 


for path in self.storedPaths {
     path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 1))
     self.fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
}